# CSS UNresponsive design

Tags: css

I have a website which I simply want to look EXACTLY the same on all devices.  I know about breakpoints etc but I don't need to consider that.  I just want to look the same on my PC, iPad, Galaxy S4 etc etc.

Is there a simple way to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: lay everything out with exact pixel positions and sizes?

Comment: As IMSoP said - if you only use absolute units for your layout then all elements should "look exactly the same". Which in reality never happens! If you really, really want to achive this, then you have to use images! It is one of the fundamental basics in web design, that a page never looks the same in different browsers, OS etc.! Maybe you should describe more precisely what you mean by "look EXACTLY the same".

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can set the viewport:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=720">
```

Comment: And which effect do you think does this have on non-mobile browsers?

Comment: None. The viewport will make your static page with a specified width look the same across devices. Most devices default to 960 but this is a nice way to control this.

Comment: "The viewport will make your static page with a specified width look the same across devices." - not really. And using the viewport meta tag with an explicit width set, is far from ideal imho! If you use it, then set `width=device-width`. If you omit it, then the so called "virtual viewport" is used. And this defaults to about 960 - 1024 pixel on most devices!

Comment: "And using the viewport meta tag with an explicit width set, is far from ideal imho!" - not the question being asked here.

Comment: OK, I try it in other words: How should your answer help the OP to achieve his goal? And why set the viewport on mobile browsers to 720 and not 320, 360 or any other value?

Comment: That's great, I'm amazed it works but so far it does seem to.  I've tested it on PC, iPad and Galaxy s4 so far.  Many thanks :)

Comment: @Netsurfer, you sound like a troll. As mentioned, the viewport will make your static page look the same across devices. I chose 720 arbitrarily. I don't think the OP cares about responsiveness. Hence, the question.